# Sharing private internet with a friend using dorm internet

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, tunnel, bridge

I live in a dorm and they provide us internet but that is slow so I am using private internet. My question is, I want to share my private internet with a friend but he can't receive my wifi signals. Is there any way my friend can access internet through my private connection using the dorm network. We both have static IPs in the dorm network. I have an extra TP-link router.

I am not sure if I had made the question clear, please ask if you need more information.

Comment: Is the connection speed between you and him slow? Or just internet access?

Comment: Do you have line of sight to your friend?

Comment: Any method you could use would go through the "slow connection" so its not worth even trying to explain how to do it.  In other words it wouldn't make the connection any faster.

Comment: There is no line of sight. He live in another building but we have common from dorm. We have slow internet access but I am sure the speed between me and him would be fast.

Comment: What do you mean by `my private internet`? Some 3G/4G modem(+router)?

Comment: Its a DSL connection. I had a router in my private internet and  a switch to connect to dorm network.

Answer (score 0):

You do need to be a bit more detailed, as @Eric Johnson asked: why is your friend unable to get your private WiFi signals? I'm guessing your friend lives on the dorm too, but too far away to get signal (which I am also guessing it is a WiFi hotspot device). Yes your friend can leach off your internet, but he has to be within reach of your PC by direct ethernet or that WiFi signal. Sadly I am fairly confident you can't share you private internet through the universities network. It may be possible, but you will either screw up their network or your own PC's (as you will need to tweak gateways, DNS, etc.)

Comment: Basically there are two networks. We both can be connected to dorm network. On the dorm network the connection between him and me is fast. Now I want him to be connected with dorm network and access internet by making his traffic go through my PC/Router(connected to dorm network) and then through my Private internet router. I hope the picture below is helpful.
<img src="http://postimg.org/image/e7z6pg16l/" width="100" height="100">

Link in case above is not working.
http://postimg.org/image/e7z6pg16l/